# NetworkManager has stopped working

Tags: windows-7, windows, boot, popups, networkmanager

Whenever I load Windows 7, the window "NetworkManager has stopped working" pops up.  Here are the problem details...

> Problem signature:   Problem Event Name:  CLR20r3
>   Problem Signature 01: NetworkManager.exe
>   Problem Signature 02: 1.1.47.1058
>   Problem Signature 03: 541c9cf1
>   Problem Signature 04: System.Drawing
>   Problem Signature 05: 4.8.3761.0
>   Problem Signature 06: 5c9c7001
>   Problem Signature 07: 30f
>   Problem Signature 08: 1a
>   Problem Signature 09: N3CTRYE2KN3C34SGL4ZQYRBFTE4M13NB
>   OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.1
>   Locale ID:    1033
>   Additional Information 1: 05d2
>   Additional Information 2: 05d208d4cb286175a12ede8b39791ca8
>   Additional Information 3: c18e
>   Additional Information 4: c18e471b7996bc4738906463e5c681a8
>
> Read our privacy statement online:
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=104288&clcid=0x0409
>
> If the online privacy statement is not available, please read our
>   privacy statement offline:   C:\Windows\system32\en-US\erofflps.txt

I do not know whether this is causing any issues behind the scenes, or is a mere annoyance, so I'm not certain if I just need to prevent the popup or actually alter the NetworkManager behavior to resolve the problem.  How can I fix this problem?

Comment: On this machine, update BIOS, both Network Drivers, all other drivers, and then open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator and run SFC /SCANNOW  .   Restart and test the network manager.

Comment: Do the local network and the internet still work?

Comment: @harrymc Yes, indeed.

Comment: @John I ran the scan, which found no issues, and all the drivers in my Device Manager were found to be up to date, except Universal Serial Bus (USB) Controller, for which Windows could not find software.  I haven't looked into the BIOS update yet.